# Overriding CSS inheritance in parent tag

Tags: html, css, inheritance, web, overriding

I have HTML and CSS as :

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Open Sans, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  font-weight: 300;
}

hr {
  display: block;
  background-color: #FFF!important;
  color: #0F0!important;
}
```

```html
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
  <hr>
</body>
```

When i run the code, the `hr` tag inherits the `body` tag style. Hence, the back-ground color surrounding the `hr` element is black #000 instead of white #FFF.

How do i override this `background-color` property being inherited from the `body` style tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the `<hr>` tag is not inheriting anything. It is just a `border` with `border-style: inset`. It has no content only a border, hence `background-color` or `color` does not mean anything to it. You can increase the `border-width` and see the colors more clearly.

In the snippet I have reproduced the same `<hr>` tags in two different backgrounds. You can see that both are the same.

If you want to add colors and other attributes, you should use a `<div>` with the required attributes instead.

```css
#page-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  font-family: Open Sans, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  font-weight: 300;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#page-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  font-family: Open Sans, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

hr {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: block;
  background-color: #FFF!important;
  color: #0F0!important;
  border-width: 10px;
}

#proper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.horizontal-rule {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-style: inset;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-top">
Black BG
  <br>
  <hr>
</div>

<div id="page-bottom">
White BG
  <br>
  <hr>
</div>

<div id="proper">
Using a div instead of hr
  <br><br>
  <div class="horizontal-rule"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This did it for me, evem though the actual 'horizontal-rule' div will be out of focus when the height of the 'proper' div is reduced. I took the 'proper' div and made it my 'hr' the border serves the purpose when the height of 'proper' style is set to 1px.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
hr {
 display: block;
 height: 1px;
 border: 0;
 border-top: 1px solid blue;
 margin: 1em 0;
 padding: 0; 
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.